# pipe a command after splitting the returned value

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I'm using a find command which results in multiple lines for result, I then want to pipe each of those lines into an ls command with the-l option specified.

```
find . -maxdepth 2  -type f |<some splitting method> | ls -l
```

I want to do this in one "command" and avoid writing to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
find . -maxdepth 2  -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

**Explanation:**

- `find . -maxdepth 2  -type f`: find files with maxdepth at 2
- `-exec ls -l {} \;` For each such result found, run `ls -l` on it; `{}` specifies where the results from find would be substituted into.

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach is to use `-exec`:

```
find . -maxdepth 2  -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for xargs. For example, on a typical Linux system:

```
find . -maxdepth 2  -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 ls -l
```